# Use segmented Control to switch between 2 views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I make an iphone application that use a segmented Control to switch between 2 viewControllers that display different informations. So, I defined in the first view Controller a segmented Control that I linked in IB to a Segmented Control that I place on the corresponding view.

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController{

//NSArray                * viewControllers;
//UINavigationController * navigationController;
IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segment; //->segment linked in the nib of FirstViewController

}
```

The action related to the segmented control is the following:

```
-(IBAction)valuechanged:(id)sender{

NSInteger index = [(UISegmentedControl *)sender selectedSegmentIndex];

UIViewController *parking=[[ParkingViewController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"ParkingViewController" bundle:nil] ;

viewControllers= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self,parking,nil];


if(index==1){
    UIViewController * incomingViewController = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:index];
    [self presentModalViewController:incomingViewController animated:YES];
            }   
}
```

In this Action, I define what to do once user click on segmented control.Here, it's loading a new viewController named ParkingViewController. The problem is that once the new ParkingViewController is loaded the segmentedControl disappear and so I can't come back to the firstViewController.

I don't know how to do to keep the segmentedControl for both views?

Thank u all

Quentin

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the UITabBarController is used to control switching between two or more view controllers.  It will stay on the screen and allow switching back and forth.

The segmented controller you have cannot stay on the screen when you present a modal view.  A modal view will take over the entire screen.  Also, because you are animating it onto the screen, a copy of the segmented view controller in the new view will not appear to be the same segmented control because the user saw it scroll onto the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I can't come back to the firstViewController... ??

> > You can add a UIButton and call an IBAction 
> >     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

Comment: I can't because my objective is to just use the segmented control to switch between my two ViewController.